# WordPress - Fatal error: Class 'WP_Widget_Tag_Cloud' not found in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wp-includes\class-wp-widget-factory.php on line 106

Tags: php, wordpress

suddenly getting this error

```
Fatal error: Class 'WP_Widget_Tag_Cloud' not found in class-wp-widget-factory.php on line 106
```

No changes at all. Deactivated all plugins and changed themes and still this error

```
public function register( $widget ) {
        if ( $widget instanceof WP_Widget ) {
            $this->widgets[ $this->hash_object( $widget ) ] = $widget;
        } else {
            $this->widgets[ $widget ] = new $widget(); // LINE 106
        }
    }
```

Any ideas?

Also now getting

```
Fatal error: Class 'Vc_Role_Access_Controller' not found in wp-content\plugins\js_composer\include\classes\core\access\class-vc-current-user-access-controller.php on line 7
```

Comment: Were any updates run? Hosting change? This couldn't have just popped up without any changes.

Comment: No. Only I have access to do this and if someone else ever did, there is a log and that shows nothing.

MySQL fell over during the night for no reason and required a server restart. I just think the server is crap.

Comment: Maybe manually reinstall Wordpress.